# No. of ways 7 digit Phone Number can be obtained

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a problem based on counting.
How many ways are there to create a 7 digit phone no provided the following two conditions are met:

1.The first digit cannot be 0 or 1.

2.The first three-digits cannot be 911.

I tried to solve it using the multiplication rule: the first digit can be selected in 7 ways (since 0,1 and 9 not allowed) and the second digit in 9 ways (since 1 not allowed) and the third digit also 9 ways (since 1 is not allowed)
and the answer I evaluated came up to $7.9.9.10^4$.

But the solution given online seems to be different.
They have evaluated the first part as $8.10^6$(without 0 or 1 as the first digit) and
then they evaluated the second part as :since 9 1 1 can be chosen in only one and the rest 4 digits can be chosen $10^4$ ways, the no of ways is $8.10^6-10^4$ which does not match my answer.

Where is my logic going wrong?

Note that there is a strange thing of sorts with my answer and the online solution. My solution is $7.9.9 .10^4$ and online solution is $799.10^4$. Is there something here that I'm not seeing? Or is this just coincidence?

Comment: Nobody said the second and third digits can't be $1$, nor that the first digit can't be $9$.  It's the specific block $911$ that is excluded.  Thus, $901-1111$ is a perfectly valid number.

Comment: Your logic excludes the nubmer 3114567, because its 2nd digit is 1.

Comment: Let me provide you with some structure in this problem. Let $A$ be the collection of seven digit phone numbers in which the first digit is not a $1$ nor a $0$, $B$ the collection of seven digit phone numbers in which the first three digits are not $911$, and $E$ the collection of all seven digits phone numbers. You need to find $|A\cap B|.$ Since $$|A \cap B|=|E|-|A^C|-|B^C|+|A^C \cap B^C|$$ We immediately get that $$|A \cap B|=10^7-2\times 10^6-10^4+0=7.99\times 10^6$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your counting is that it excludes any phone-number that has a 9 in the first digit, a 1 in the second digit, and a 1 in the third digit (ex 9012345 is a valid phone number, but isn't counted in your method). To fix this we could use the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) alongside your original count.

There are $10^6$ numbers with the first digit as 9, $8\cdot10^5$ numbers with a 1 as the second digit, and $8\cdot10^5$ numbers with a 1 as the third digit. There are $10^5$ numbers with a 9 as the first digit and a 1 as the second and by symmetry, there are $10^5$ numbers with a 9 in the first digit and a 1 in the third digit. There are $8\cdot10^4$ numbers with a 1 in both the first and second digit. We can't have a number with a 9 in the first digit, 1 in the second digit, and 1 in the third because that would violate the 911 restriction.

Adding this information to your original count gives
$10^{6}+2\left(8\cdot10^{5}\right)-2\cdot10^{5}-8\cdot10^{4}+7\cdot9\cdot9\cdot10^{4}=799\cdot10^4$, matching the solution.

As mentioned in the solution, using complementary counting is an easier way to solve this problem, since it's easier to count the numbers that we *don't* want than count the numbers we do want. There are $10^4$ numbers that violate the 911 restriction, so the number of valid numbers can be counted by $8\cdot10^6-10^4=799 \cdot 10^4$ (where the $8\cdot10^6$ comes from the restriction on the first digit).

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong in that the first digit can be $9$. One specific case is $9999999$ which is allowed. What you need to do is have $8\times10^6$ and minus the case where the first three digits are $911$ in that order, which is $10^4$. And yes, the solution is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

First digit cannot be '0', so 100 numbers are out. First digit cannot be '1', another 100 numbers are out. Among the remaining 800 numbers, only '911' is not allowed, so you can choose between 799 numbers for the first three digits.